Cosmos DB consuming more RU's for PATCH
I'm using cosmos db with 1500 RU/s for one container, and i have an item like
{
    "id": "9295a327-wert-434f-34r5-f89e9d05a800",
    "Name": "NAME_NAME",
   {
    "users":{
       "4f5c0361-377f-4fa3-b18f-asdffe60b806": {
          "FullName": "Full Name",
          "EmailID": "Full.Name@mail.com"
      }
   }
}

When i'm trying to add new user to the "users", using patch operations it is taking high RU/s. i have 4k items in users, patch is taking around 2.5K~ RU/s when i try to add single user.
Below is the java code i'm using:
PartitionKey partitionKey = new PartitionKey("key");
            CosmosPatchOperations operations = CosmosPatchOperations.create();
            operations.add("/users/".concat("id"),
                    new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
                        put("FullName", user.getFullName());
                        put("EmailID", user.emailID);
                    }});
            GroupEntity patch = cosmosTemplate.patch("id", partitionKey, Entity.class,
                    operations);

Is this expected behaviour or am i missing something.
updated:
Reading entire document takes 26 RU. and i'm using id as partition key.

What are you comparing it against to conclude that it's high? Are you comparing it with a Replace?

fyi - you have a data-modeling issue (an anti-pattern), as you're using the id inside users as a key, instead of a value. If you're going to have multiple users, then 1) use an array or move to a separate document per user; and 2) have a property like userid and then the actual id as a value.

Also, you haven't mentioned any details about your partition key (which property is it?). And how does the patch cost compare to, say, a read or a query of that item (or as already mentioned, a replace)?

@MatiasQuaranta, Reading the entire document takes 26 RU, i'm a bit concerned while adding single user why the RU charge is so high.

@DavidMakogon, I'm using id as partition key

You have 4K sub objects in the users object? Patch replaces the whole document. It doesn't just surgically insert it in place to the existing document. These should very likely be stored as separate documents not appended one at a time to an ever growing document

thanks, @MartinSmith, Patch replaces the whole document!!!, could you share where this is addressed. But I didn't understand, why Get call is taking a percent of RU than Patch

The patch operation means the system needs to read the document, make a change to it and then write it back. So is basically a read plus a delete plus an insert with some compute cost. The docs do say Users should not expect a significant reduction in RU - the advantages of Patch are simplifying updates, avoiding the need to send the whole document to the client first and concurrency not reduced RU.

And as for why writing a document with thousands of properties is much more expensive than reading the same document a lot of the cost will be due to index maintenance for all of these properties - with wildcard indexing by default everything is indexed. But even without wildcard indexing it still won't be a cheap operation.

Got it @MartinSmith, as suggested, I have decoupled the users to separate container, now i'm mapping id from the parent in above json to user under a field.
